# Hyper-V port access lists do not allow traffic past gateway

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

A situation: The local network of 192.168.0.0/16 is split into many subnets, and routers are in place. A Hyper-V hosted virtual machine is located in a 192.168.X.0/24 subnet. The task was given to limit access to this VM from all hosts except a given list, which contains IP addresses from 192.168.Y.0/24 subnets, where Y is different from X and network access to 192.168.Y.0/24 subnet is routed. The configuration of VM's network is as follows:

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.X.10
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.X.1
```

So I perform the following alterations on the Hyper-V port ACL:

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapterAcl -vm $vm -RemoteIPAddress 192.168.Y.Z -action allow -direction both
Add-VMNetworkAdapterAcl -vm $vm -RemoteIPAddress any -action deny -direction both
```

To my surprise, `ping 192.168.Y.Z` showed "Destination host unreachable" from the VM, also pinging the VM from that host returned the same. On the other hand, if I add an ACL entry to `192.168.X.Z` to the same VM, the change allows VM to see the host without hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add an ACL entry for the VM's default gateway, or, in case of a custom route to the 192.168.Y subnet, the IP address of the route destination, to allow packets to be routed through to the remote host.

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapterAcl -vm $vm -RemoteIPAddress 192.168.X.1 -action allow -direction both
```

This, sadly, is not mentioned in any tutorials for configuring the ACLs for Hyper-V, probably due to the face that the LANs in these tutorials are as simple as possible, and don't contain routed segments.